# Install Cloud Foundry CLI in a M1 chip MacBook

Tags: cloud-foundry, apple-m1

**tl;dr** The Cloud Foundry CLI fails to install in an M1 chip MacBook Pro.

Following the [official instructions](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html#pkg-mac), using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) in the command:

```
$ brew install cloudfoundry/tap/cf-cli@8
```

The output is:

```
cf-cli@8: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
Error: cf-cli@8: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Found no binary for the ARM-based architecture of the Apple M1 chip. The same trying with `cf-cli@7`, or just `cf-cli`.

How can the Cloud Foundry CLI be installed in an ARM-based architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of v8.4.0 a few days ago the support for ARM based mac OS machines (e.g. M1) was added:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/commit/69f268f18ea10a4c8e19c99a8bb209c1ebbcbe7d

It will still fail if you only tap it and leave out the version in your install command, so you'll need to enter:

```bash
brew install cloudfoundry/tap/cf-cli@8
```

Answer (score 3):

The official GitHub project `cloudfoundry/cli` includes binaries for many architectures, including ARM-based.

Search in the official [Releases](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases) page, Assets section, and download the binary of the item named [cf-cli_osx_arm](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases/download/v8.3.0/cf-cli_osx_arm) (currently v8.3.0). Once downloaded, move/rename to any folder included in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/2131) for this.

Until the official tap supports the osx_arm binary, you can use [this unofficial tap](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/2131#issuecomment-1096165596) which is manually updated:

```
brew install wanddynosios/tap/cf-cli
```

That said, it seems like the official CloudFoundry maintainers [are about to support this officially](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/2131#issuecomment-1101786776) soon.